# Are Sith Lords celibate like the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, sith

The Sith are disciplined Force-wielders, but I’m not sure if this means that they are sexually abstinent.

Comment: Some Jedi have had children, but I've never heard of any Sith having children. I think the Sith are too busy plotting to kill each other, dominate the galaxy, and destroy the Jedi, than to give in to temptations of the flesh.

Comment: I'm sure there has been a Sith Mistress and Apprentice romance in some fan-fic!

Comment: Vader certainly is.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I hope this doesn't come as a shock to you, but people perform horizontal gymnastic for pleasure and fun, not to have children.

Comment: @motoDrizzt - Or because they're bored.

Comment: And for what it is worth, my impression wasn't that the Jedi are celibate, but rather that they're encouraged to "not form lasting attachments". So probably one-night-stands and prostitutes are still on the table.

Comment: Does [Revan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Revan) count? He married [Bastila Shan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bastila_Shan) when he turned back to the light.

Comment: Are we talking Disney cannon, or sw legends because the answer is different

Comment: I’m sure that Darth Maul could “get some” if he wanted it. I can’t believe that Yoda and Obi-Wan “stayed abstinent” after the Jedi Purge.

Comment: Didnt Malgus have a baby with that Twilek that he later killed? was it in a book or a SWTOR cinematic i remember this from??

Comment: @FrankRodriguez - Darth Maul pre or post-Phantom Menace ending?

Comment: "Through passion I gain strength" baby, plenty of room to get busy.

Answer (score 5):

#### Canon

There is nothing in the [Code of the Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Code_of_the_Sith) which forbids sex for the Sith. Indeed, the Code's declaration of the existence of passion indicates that the Sith embrace passion (mainly anger, but possibly also sexual passion). This is in contrast to the [Jedi Code](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Code) which denies emotion and passion and therefore encourages sexual abstinence for the Jedi.

That said, to the best of my knowledge there has been no depiction of a Sith having a sexual encounter in canon. Since sex is not against the Code of the Sith it's a possibility that Sith Lord(s) have had minor sexual encounters which are just not worth mentioning. In general, however, the Sith are seduced by *power* rather than sex; they are probably so obsessed with power that they don't really care much about sex. It's not that they are opposed to sex, it's just that it's a low priority for them.

#### Legends

Sith have definitely had sexual encounters in Legends. Notable examples include [Darth Malgus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Malgus) who took a Twi'lek slave girl named [Eleena Daru](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Eleena_Daru) as his lover, and [Tenebrae/Vitiate/Valkorion](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vitiate) who had three children by [Senya Tirall](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Senya_Tirall). These characters are depicted the video game [*Star Wars: The Old Republic*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_The_Old_Republic), which allows Sith players to have sexual encounters (off-screen, not actually depicted) with some of the other characters they meet. As in canon, there is no mention of lovers for most of the [Banite Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Order_of_the_Sith_Lords), possibly because these Sith were few in number and in hiding. Legends does suggest that [Palpatine had concubines after he became emperor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Palpatine/Legends), though it's not certain that these women were physically intimate with him.

Comment: What about Ventress (ex-Sith apprentice) and that Jedi guy who later became Dooku's apprentice after falling to the dark side?

Comment: you mean [Quinlan Vos](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Quinlan_Vos)

Comment: @Adamant While *affiliated* with the Sith, neither were ever one of the two actual Sith (Master and Apprentice). Therefore I don't think any sexual encounters by such characters count.